# HTTP reverse tunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel, tunneling

### Question

Is it possible to use a socks tunnel (or any other form of tunnel on port 80 or 443) to control the local machine that is creating the tunnel from the remote machine? Basically, a `ssh -R [...]`  when `ssh` is not an option and only TCP connection on port `80` and `443` are possible?

### Concrete scenario

Due to a very restrictive security policy of one of our customers, we currently have to connect to a Windows jump host without the ability to copy-and-paste stuff there. From there, we download needed files via web browser and copy via ssh to the target machine, or use `ssh` directly to do maintenance work on the target machine. However, this workflow is time-consuming, and honestly quite annoying.

Unfortunately, the firewall seems to be able to distinguish between real HTTP traffic and ssh as opening instructing `sshd` on our server to accept connections on `443` did not work.

```
Firewall
(HTTP only)
┌──────────────┐
│              │
│  ┌─────────┐ │ ???    ┌──────────┐
│  │Jumphost ├─┼───────►│Our Server│
│  │(Windows)│ │        └───▲──────┘
│  └──┬──────┘ │            │
│     │ssh     │            │ssh
│     │        │            │
│   ┌─▼─────┐  │        ┌───┴─────┐
│   │Target │  │        │Developer│
│   │(Linux)│  │        │Machine  │
│   └───────┘  │        └─────────┘
│              │
└──────────────┘
```

Any hints are highly appreciated

Comment: If the customer don't want it, he has to pay your time, but it seems to be a bad idea to circumvent his security

Comment: You could try opening a websocket, they use TCP connections and support full duplex data traffic. I don't know anything about the systems though therefore I can't tell you how to open a websocket, but javascript can do that as an example.

Comment: @jeb I do not see how we circumvent anything. As long as the connection from the jumphost to our server is secure, I do not see any vulnerability introduced by this.

Comment: @DFSFOT that is certainly an option. However, I am unaware of any software that lets you do such a thing :/

Comment: @NickLehmann You could try NodeJS or opening a websocket with javascript in the browser. I just realized though that ssh usually runs over TCP as well, so if you can't run a connection using ssh then it's not ssh being blocked, but probably a lot of TCP based protocols. You might still be able to use websockets though since they're HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a firewall with deep packet inspection.

You can overcome it with using ssh over ssl, using `stunnel` or `openssl`.
From the windows box you can tunnel with a stunnel client to `our-server` stunnel server.
That encapsulate all (ssh) data into ssl therefore there is no difference to a HTTPS connection.

Another option could be ptunnel-ng, it supports a tcp connection over ICMP (ping).

Most firewalls ignores ICMP, if you can ping your `our-server` this should work, too.
But ptunnel-ng seems sometimes a bit unstable.

If you can't install/execute programs on the windows jumbBox, you can open ports, redirect them by ssh and use them directly by the target-linux.

On your windows jumpbox:

```
ssh target -R target:7070:our-server:443
```

On the target (linux) you can use `localhost:7070` to connect to `our-server:443`

I would recommend to use docker for the client and server parts.
I only can't use the ptunnel server inside a container, probably because of the required privileges.

### Using ptunnel

#### On the server

The ptunnel binary is build inside docker, but used by the host directly
This sample expects an ubuntu server

Dockerfile.server

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf automake git
RUN mkdir -p /workdir
WORKDIR /workdir
RUN git clone https://github.com/lnslbrty/ptunnel-ng.git && cd ptunnel-ng && ./autogen.sh
```

start-server.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Starts the icmp tunnel server, this doesn't work inside a docker container
# Or perhaps it works, but I dont't know how
script_dir=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
if [ ! -f $script_dir/ptunnel-ng ]; then
  # Build the ptunnel binary and copy it to the host
  docker build -t ptunnel-ng-build-server -f $script_dir/Dockerfile.server $script_dir
  docker run --rm -v $script_dir:/shared ptunnel-ng-build-server cp /workdir/ptunnel-ng/src/ptunnel-ng /shared
fi

magic=${1-123456}
sudo $script_dir/ptunnel-ng --magic $magic
```

#### On the client

```
FROM alpine:latest as builder
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk bash autoconf automake git
RUN mkdir -p /workdir
WORKDIR /workdir 
RUN git clone https://github.com/lnslbrty/ptunnel-ng.git && cd ptunnel-ng && ./autogen.sh

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /workdir 
COPY --from=builder /workdir/ptunnel-ng/src/ptunnel-ng .
```

start-client.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

image=ptunnel-ng
if ! docker inspect $image > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then
  docker build -t $image .
fi

magic=${1-123456}
ptunnel_host=${2-myserver.de}
port=${3-2001}

docker run --rm --detach -ti --name 'ptunnel1' -v $PWD:/shared -p 2222:2222 $image //workdir/ptunnel-ng --magic ${magic} -p${ptunnel_host} -l${port}
```

If you try to run the ptunnel client on termux, this can be done, but requires some small code changes

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give it a try!