# Can HTTP/2 CONNECT be used as a reverse tunnel?

Tags: http, envoyproxy, tunnel, quic, http-tunneling

Is it possible to use HTTP/2 `CONNECT` or HTTP/3 QUIC `CONNECT` connection as a *reverse tunnel* such that the server end can multiplex HTTP requests *back down the tunnel* to the connection initiator?

This would require the HTTP server to be able to create new streams on a client-initiated connection.

Or are HTTP/2 `CONNECT` streams strictly client-initiated and client-controlled?

---

Context:

I'm looking to expose services on a NAT'd host to a central control hub. Both the edge services and the control hub are on separate, independent k8s clusters. Only the central hub has a public-routable IP address.

Most of the k8s-native east-west-routing and service mesh options that support service discovery and virtual services cannot be used because tools like Istio and Consul require mutual reachability.

I'm aware of the typical options such as `ssh -R`, wireguard VPN, etc, but for a variety of reasons they're going to be awkward and difficult to use in this environment. Something based on HTTP+TLS will work a lot better. I could possibly tunnel tunnel ssh over HTTP CONNECT then use ssh to reverse-tunnel the requests, for example, but the layering is probably going to do ugly things to TCP.

I've been looking into whether it's possible to configure the Envoy proxy to accept inbound HTTP/2 `CONNECT` from an external service, then use that inbound connection as a listener to route other requests through. But I can't find any hint that it's even possible.

(Based on a quick reading of the Teleport code, [Teleport Proxy uses the ssh protocol for reverse tunnels to the Teleport Agent](https://github.com/gravitational/teleport/blob/master/lib/reversetunnel/conn.go#L148C63-L148C63). There's an "inlets pro" tool that does something similar over HTTPs but it looks like it's 1:1 tunnels only. I haven't been able to find anything like a simple tool to expose a SOCKS proxy over a client-initiated HTTP tunnel, or do remote-port-forwarding (ssh -R style) over a client-initiated HTTP tunnel.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747170/http-reverse-tunnel

Comment: After 2-3 days of digging I found https://github.com/hotnops/gtunnel which looks like ... well, if not exactly it, then what I'm looking for which is a HTTP/2 based reverse proxy

Comment: For the sake of cross-referencing, related question posted in https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-multi-network-multi-mesh-hub-and-spoke-with-no-listening-ports-on-spokes-passive-reverse-tunnel/16865

Comment: From what I can tell the answer to my question is "no, HTTP/2 can't directly be used to open new server-to-client streams over an existing connection". However, the client can long-poll the server for command-and-control requests, where the server replies to ask the client to open a new stream on the connection. Then that can be used to reverse tunnel a connection's data. The downside is an extra full round trip plus new stream overhead. I'd love to be wrong about this if someone corrects me...

Comment: Also posted to envoy-users here https://groups.google.com/g/envoy-users/c/rE3PfA7kgyQ/m/UrnMA2SaBwAJ

Comment: Related Envoy github issue https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/22697

Comment: Asked about it on k8s Gateways API working group discussion pages https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gateway-api/discussions/2490

Comment: For others with this problem it looks like GOST https://gost.run/en/tutorials/reverse-proxy-advanced/ and Boring Proxy https://boringproxy.io/ can do this. From what I've been looking at, it also looks like HTTP/3 over QUIC should be able to establish back-connections without requiring the downstream to initiate. Am looking for confirmation. Istio's upcoming ambient mesh with HBONE looks like it might be capable of bi-directional tunnels but again unconfirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be "no, it can't". You need a command-and-control channel where client-side long-polls the "server" side. The server makes requests for new channels over the control channel, and the client initiates them.

It's unclear if this is possible server-side with HTTP/3 over QUIC, or over WebSockets, but for HTTP/2 it looks like a "no".